# Mustache + nested objects

Tags: javascript, templates, mustache

I'm trying to create a tree from a list of tags which have tags inside them.

Here's a sample of the JSON I'm using :

```
{
  "tags":
  [{"name":"My first tag",
    "tags":
    [{"name":"My first tag inside a tag"},
     {"name":"My second tag inside a tag"}]
  }]
}
```

If I use the following mustache template, it displays "My first tag" without any problems :

```
<ul>
{{#tags}}
<li tag-id="{{id}}">
  {{name}}
</li>
{{/tags}}
</ul>
```

But then, using the following template, I'm trying to display the tags inside this first tag :

```
<ul>
{{#tags}}
<li tag-id="{{id}}">
  {{name}}
  <div>
  {{#tags}}
    <a>{{name}}</a>
  {{/tags}}
  </div>
</li>
{{/tags}}
</ul>
```

Using this template, Mustache doesn't render anything.

**How do I display nested lists using Mustache?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To solve that issue, I will do:

```
<div id="result-tag"></div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function test(){
  var view = {
    "tags":
    [{"name":"My first tag",
      "tags":
      [{"name":"My first tag inside a tag"},
       {"name":"My second tag inside a tag"}]
    }]
  };

  var templt = '<ul>{{#tags}}<li>{{name}}<div>{{>subtags}}</div></li>{{/tags}}</ul>';
  var partials = {"subtags": "{{#tags}}<a>{{name}}</a><br/>{{/tags}}"};
  var html = Mustache.to_html(templt, view, partials);
  document.getElementById('result-tag').innerHTML=html;
}
window.onload = test;
</script>
```

I hope that helps

Comment: I'll try it today, I'll get back to you ! Thanks.

Comment: Works great!
I actually had a problem because I was using $('#my-template').html() and it replaces ">" with "&gt;", I had to use replace('&gt;', '>')